# grab and display table data in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

in My Laravel 5.2 application I have tasks table like this

```
 id      task_name      project_id
    1         aaa               1
    2         hjhkj             2
    3         jhghg             1
    4         jgsdygu           3
    5         gdggfv            2
```

now I am going to display task names for  to relevant each project_id in My index.blade.php file in tasks folder in resource file.

I am using this codes for this

```
@foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
    <h4><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a></h4>
@endforeach
```

now I can seen with tasks name relevant to each project_id. but now I need to click on each task name and display project_id, task id and task name in show.blade.php file witch located in task folder how can do this?

Comment: Same as you did this - create controller, get data, output in blade-template.

Comment: I need some idea about controller codes...

Comment: Select data by `task_id` provided in request.

Comment: can I view data without controller method?

Comment: Something on server should return data. It can be either controller or simple file.